# Add a timer to close Ajax Quick Cart (Shopify) after product is added to cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've successfully set up the Shopify Ajax Cart using the [Timber framework](http://timber-demo.myshopify.com) so currently my cart closes if you click anywhere outside of the cart (or using the close button).

I want to be able to create a timer so that after a product has been added to the cart and the ajax quick cart opens it then closes after say 5 seconds so the user can continue to shop. If they want to view the cart for longer they can hit the cart button to reopen and from there click the link to the full cart page.

It was suggested to me that I can close the cart with timber.RightDrawer.close(); and I should set it up in a listener like the one below however being new to JS I'm struggling with where to begin.

```
jQuery('body').on('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', function(evt, cart) {
    // start timer function

    // when timer is triggered:
    timber.rightDrawer.close();
});
```

I've tried the following but I'm really just guessing...

```
jQuery('body').on('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', function(evt, cart) {
    // start timer function
    $('#AddToCart').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        // when timer is triggered:
        timber.rightDrawer.close();
        },500);
    });
});
```

Some of my current code as follows, see Timber framework for same setup as mine:

theme.liquid JS:

```
{% comment %}
Ajaxify your cart with this plugin.
Documentation:
- http://shopify.com/timber#ajax-cart
{% endcomment %}
{% if settings.ajax_cart_enable %}
  {{ 'handlebars.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% include 'ajax-cart-template' %}
  {{ 'ajax-cart.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      ajaxCart.init({
       formSelector: '#AddToCartForm',
       cartContainer: '#CartContainer',
       addToCartSelector: '#AddToCart',
       cartCountSelector: '#CartCount',
       cartCostSelector: '#CartCost',
       moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }}
     });
   });

jQuery('body').on('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', function(evt, cart) {
  // Bind to 'ajaxCart.afterCartLoad' to run any javascript after the cart has loaded in the DOM

  timber.RightDrawer.open();
});
</script>
{% endif %}
```

timber.js.liquid:

```
timber.drawersInit = function () {
   timber.LeftDrawer = new timber.Drawers('NavDrawer', 'left');
   timber.RightDrawer = new timber.Drawers('CartDrawer', 'right',
   'onDrawerOpen': ajaxCart.load
   });
};

timber.Drawers = (function () {
  var Drawer = function (id, position, options) {
  var defaults = {
  close: '.js-drawer-close',
  open: '.js-drawer-open-' + position,
  openClass: 'js-drawer-open',
  dirOpenClass: 'js-drawer-open-' + position
};

this.$nodes = {
  parent: $('body, html'),
  page: $('#PageContainer'),
  moved: $('.is-moved-by-drawer')
};

this.config = $.extend(defaults, options);
this.position = position;

this.$drawer = $('#' + id);

if (!this.$drawer.length) {
  return false;
}

this.drawerIsOpen = false;
this.init();
  };

 Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy(this.open, this));
this.$drawer.find(this.config.close).on('click', $.proxy(this.close, this));
};

  Drawer.prototype.open = function (evt) {
// Keep track if drawer was opened from a click, or called by another function
var externalCall = false;

// Prevent following href if link is clicked
if (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
} else {
  externalCall = true;
}

// Without this, the drawer opens, the click event bubbles up to $nodes.page
// which closes the drawer.
if (evt && evt.stopPropagation) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  // save the source of the click, we'll focus to this on close
  this.$activeSource = $(evt.currentTarget);
}

if (this.drawerIsOpen && !externalCall) {
  return this.close();
}

// Add is-transitioning class to moved elements on open so drawer can have
// transition for close animation
this.$nodes.moved.addClass('is-transitioning');
this.$drawer.prepareTransition();

this.$nodes.parent.addClass(this.config.openClass + ' ' + this.config.dirOpenClass);
this.drawerIsOpen = true;

// Run function when draw opens if set
if (this.config.onDrawerOpen && typeof(this.config.onDrawerOpen) == 'function') {
  if (!externalCall) {
    this.config.onDrawerOpen();
  }
}

if (this.$activeSource && this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded')) {
  this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
}

// Lock scrolling on mobile
this.$nodes.page.on('touchmove.drawer', function () {
  return false;
});

this.$nodes.page.on('click.drawer', $.proxy(function () {
  this.close();
  return false;
}, this));
  };

  Drawer.prototype.close = function () {
if (!this.drawerIsOpen) { // don't close a closed drawer
  return;
}

// deselect any focused form elements
$(document.activeElement).trigger('blur');

// Ensure closing transition is applied to moved elements, like the nav
this.$nodes.moved.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });
this.$drawer.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });

this.$nodes.parent.removeClass(this.config.dirOpenClass + ' ' + this.config.openClass);

this.drawerIsOpen = false;

this.$nodes.page.off('.drawer');
  };

  return Drawer;
})();

// Initialize Timber's JS on docready
$(timber.init);
```

Comment: I've updated my question which something I've tried but isn't currently working am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Is your ajaxCart.afterCartLoad listener getting called? Your code looks good so debug the code (using the developer tools in Safari or Chrome or Firebug in Firefox) or else add an alert in the listener to be sure it's getting called like you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setinterval to set the time to 5s

```
     jQuery('body').on('click','#AddToCart', function(evt, cart) {

  timber.RightDrawer.open();

       var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
        timber.RightDrawer.close();
        clearInterval(myVar);
        }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't setTimeout be preferred to setInterval since it runs only once and you don't have to add the extra code to clear the interval?

Comment: I tried something like this earlier and couldn't get it to work. Also just tried your code snippet and that doesn't seem to work either. I wonder if I'm putting it in the wrong place? I'm currently putting it just before the closing script tag in my theme.liquid template.

Comment: This works perfectly except I just need it to be applied to when the #AddtoCart button is clicked. Would I just wrap it in a function like in my example in my original question above?

Comment: I tried both options the second breaks it, the first works once and then doesn't work again. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: because of the event updated the second part of the code

Comment: It's only doing the timer if you open the cart via the cart button and then add something to the cart via the add to cart button. When you say because of the event would you mind explaining what you mean? Thank you for all your help by the way.

Comment: the code from the first paragraf executes the code once because of the event: ajaxCart.afterCartLoad that fires once at dom load and after that the click event isn't trigered anymore

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining that and updating it seems to be working now. Do I need both parts or just the second part?

Comment: you can remove it from the first part